# C# deserializing nested elements with only one item

Tags: c#, xml, nested, xml-serialization, deserialization

I use C# to deserialize a XML file. My XML file has the format:

```xml
<Produced_by >
    <Producing_Unit>
        <Unit ID="" Name=""/>
    </Producing_Unit>
</Produced_by>
```

When ***deserializing*** I want to remove the middleman Producing_Unit. Since Produced_by will always contain only one subelement Producing_Unit specifying the Unit.
My initial thoughts on how to implement doesn't work:

```cs
public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Produced_by
{
    [XmlElement("Producing_Unit")]
    [XmlElement("Unit")]
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

It could be soleved by using [XmlArray("Producing_Unit"), XmlArrayItem("Unit")]
and then having Produced_by contain: public List<Unit> {get;set;}. But that's not what I want.

Comment: Try putting the XMLElement properties in the Unit class, and above it's properties.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to use the XML with the "Producing_Unit" tag but ditch the matching `Producing_Unit` class with the standard attributes short of implementing the [`IXmlSerializable` interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) Your best bet would be to separate your application/business logic from your serialization layer. Keep your serialization simple and matching your XML schema, then simply convert to/from that data model and a cleaner data model (without `Producing_Unit`) for the rest of your application to work with.

Comment: @Ramie Could you give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to use the XML with the "Producing_Unit" tag but ditch the matching `Producing_Unit` class with the standard attributes short of implementing the [`IXmlSerializable` interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) Your best bet would be to separate your application/business logic from your serialization layer.

Keep your serialization data model simple and matching your XML schema (this means including the wrapping `Producing_Unit` class), then simply convert to/from that data model and a cleaner data model (without `Producing_Unit`) for the rest of your application to work with.

---

EDIT: Here's an implementation using the `IXmlSerializable` interface. I just whipped it off and honestly, don't know if it will work for all cases.

```
public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Produced_by : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Produced_by");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Producing_Unit");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Unit");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", this.Unit.ID);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", this.Unit.Name);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name == "Unit")
            {
                this.Unit = new Unit()
                {
                    Name = reader.GetAttribute("Name"),
                    ID = reader.GetAttribute("ID")
                };

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return(null);
    }
}
```

I suspect that I'm performing the reading in a poor fashion, but this works in my local test. I still recommend separating your application and serialization concerns though and avoiding having to write an implementation like this.

Comment: I have a XML file i want to deseralize, not the other way around.

Comment: @bjar-bjar: Ahh, so the first XML sample you posted (with the wrapping "Producing_Unit" tag) is the fixed XML you want work with, but you don't want to require having the 3rd middleman `Producing_Unit` class?

Comment: That's exactly my problem.

Comment: @bjar-bjar: I edited my answer. Sorry, I don't think it's possible to achieve this with the built-in XML serialization attributes.

Comment: @bjar-bjar: I edited my answer yet again; I've included a working implementation of `IXmlSerializable`. I still don't recommend using it, but in my local test it works fine.

Comment: Well my XML file is huge (~20 mB) with a lot of tags arranged like my question, which is why I want a simple and effective solution. You solved the problem, but it does not help me. I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Producing_Unit
{
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
}

public class Produced_by
{
    private Producing_Unit producing_unit;

    public Producing_Unit Producing_Unit //This can't be auto-implemented since can write to properties of properties.
    { 
        get { return producing_Unit; } 
        set { producing_Unit = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public Unit Unit
    {
        get { return producing_Unit.Unit; }
        set { producing_Unit.Unit = value; }
    }
}
```

Yes, it doesn't get rid of the 'middle-men,' but you can ignore them.